# Importing Gift Records

Tags: import

Does anyone know here know how to import .csv files containing contribution information?
I know how to import constituent records but don't know how to import their gifts.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation for that lives here:

```
https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/common-workflows/importing-data-into-civicrm/#import-contributions
```